# Extending Django's User model does not populate auth.user

Tags: django, django-authentication

So, I have extended Django's User model (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model).

Here are my model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name = 'email address',unique = True, db_index = True)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    ...

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

In the registration form:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Form for registering a new account
    """

    email = forms.EmailField(widget = forms.widgets.TextInput,
                             label = 'Email',
                             )
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget = forms.widgets.PasswordInput,
                               label = 'password'
                               )
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget = forms.widgets.PasswordInput,
                                label = 'password (again)'
                                )


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'user_type']

    ...

    def save(self, commit = True):

        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit = False)

        the_password = self.cleaned_data['password1']

        user.set_password(the_password) # This Hashes the password before saving it

        if commit:
            user.save()            
            return user
```

and finally, in the views.py:

```
class Registration(View):
    signup_form = RegistrationForm
    template_name = 'accounts/signup.html'

    def post(self, request):
        the_signup_form = self.signup_form(request.POST if any(request.POST) else None)
        ...
        if the_signup_form.is_valid():
            cleaned_signup_form = the_signup_form.cleaned_data
            the_user = the_signup_form.save()  # User is saved. 
            return redirect('/')
```

Now, the problem is that after submitting the form, the custom User model's table is populated fine, but Django's "auth_user" table is NOT! I thought calling *user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit = False)* would take care of saving to the based class.  And, so of course, when I try to authenticate:

```
this_user = authenticate(email = the_user.email,
                         password = the_user.password)
```

this_user is None, so it will not login the user.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

`AbstractBaseUser` is an [abstract base class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes), there is no table created for it.

When you set `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'` in your settings, your `User` model will be used **instead** of the `django.contrib.auth.models.User` model, so you shouldn't have an `auth_user` table at all.

When you call `super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)`, this calls the save method of the parent class `ModelForm`, it has nothing to do with the `django.contrib.auth.models.User` model.

Answer (score 0):

Extending from `AbstractBaseUser` you get a similar to built-in `User` model class.

From the link you provided:

> AbstractBaseUser provides the core implementation of a User model,
>   including hashed passwords and tokenized password resets.

So, you're not actually using `django.contrib.auth.models.User`, you can always extend from `django.contrib.auth.models.User` to add some attributes, or create a new model and link to django's `User` model with a 1:1 relationship.